# How do I respond to "there is no root file system" message while installing Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, installation

I am currently running Ubuntu 18, "try without installing" option. I am trying to install it. I have partitioned one of my hard disks in order to get a place to install.

When I try to continue it says "root file system not defined, please fix it in the partition menu".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main Linux partition must be mounted as `/`, it must hold a proper file system (e.g. ext4) from the very beginning. It may be the only partition used by Linux or there may be others mounted e.g. as `/boot`, `/var`, `/home`, etc.

While `/boot` (or `/var` etc.) may be a mount point for a separate partition or just a normal directory inside `/`, `/` itself as a *mount point* is mandatory. You need to assign `/` to some partition and create (format) a file system there (if not already created).

Example:

[image: partial screenshot]